# Is it possible to make this code more concise using mutate_at or by using another approach?

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

I'm still learning R. I've got a piece of code and I'd like to learn how to make it more concise for my future work:

```
test <- function (x,logical) {
  if (logical == FALSE) {
    return (NA)
  }  else{
    return (x)
  }
}

merged_dataframe2 <- merge(merged_dataframe, dataframe, by = "dmt") %>%
                     rowwise() %>%
                     mutate(MaxFlow_logical = case_when(((MaxFlow < (MaxFlow_q1 - MaxFlow_iqr)) | (MaxFlow > (MaxFlow_q3 + MaxFlow_iqr))) ~ FALSE,
                                                          TRUE ~ TRUE),
                            Morning_mean_logical = case_when(((Morning_mean < (Morning_mean_q1 - Morning_mean_iqr)) | (Morning_mean > (Morning_mean_q3 + Morning_mean_iqr))) ~ FALSE,
                                                               TRUE ~ TRUE),
                            Afternoon_mean_logical = case_when(((Afternoon_mean < (Afternoon_mean_q1 - Afternoon_mean_iqr)) | (Afternoon_mean > (Afternoon_mean_q3 + Afternoon_mean_iqr))) ~ FALSE,
                                                                 TRUE ~ TRUE),
                            Evening_mean_logical = case_when(((Evening_mean < (Evening_mean_q1 - Evening_mean_iqr)) | (Evening_mean > (Evening_mean_q3 + Evening_mean_iqr))) ~ FALSE,
                                                               TRUE ~ TRUE),
                            Morn_cons_logical = case_when(((Morn_cons < (Morn_cons_q1 - Morn_cons_iqr)) | (Morn_cons > (Morn_cons_q3 + Morn_cons_iqr))) ~ FALSE,
                                                            TRUE ~ TRUE),
                            Eve_cons_logical = case_when(((Eve_cons < (Eve_cons_q1 - Eve_cons_iqr)) | (Eve_cons > (Eve_cons_q3 + Eve_cons_iqr))) ~ FALSE,
                                                           TRUE ~ TRUE),
                            min_night_flow_logical = case_when(((min_night_flow < (min_night_flow_q1 - min_night_flow_iqr)) | (min_night_flow > (min_night_flow_q3 + min_night_flow_iqr))) ~ FALSE,
                                                                 TRUE ~ TRUE),
                            mean_night_flow_logical = case_when(((mean_night_flow < (mean_night_flow_q1 - mean_night_flow_iqr)) | (mean_night_flow > (mean_night_flow_q3 + mean_night_flow_iqr))) ~ FALSE,
                                                                  TRUE ~ TRUE),
                            Morning_mean = test(Morning_mean,Morning_mean_logical),
                            Afternoon_mean = test(Afternoon_mean,Afternoon_mean_logical),
                            Evening_mean = test(Evening_mean,Evening_mean_logical),
                            Morn_cons = test(Morn_cons,Morn_cons_logical),
                            Eve_cons = test(Eve_cons,Eve_cons_logical),
                            min_night_flow = test(min_night_flow,min_night_flow_logical),
                            mean_night_flow = test(mean_night_flow,mean_night_flow_logical))
```

Is it possible to use a mutate_at to make this more concise?

I've used case_when to output logical columns. Is there a way of combining these steps so you don't have to create logical columns. Something like this:

```
MaxFlow_logical = case_when(((MaxFlow < (MaxFlow_q1 - MaxFlow_iqr)) | (MaxFlow > (MaxFlow_q3 + MaxFlow_iqr))) ~ NA, TRUE ~ MaxFlow)
```

However this does not work, is there an alternative?

Comment: Don't test logical values by comparing to `FALSE` or to `TRUE`, the condition `logical == FALSE` should be replaced by `!logical` or by `isFALSE(logical)`.

Comment: You probably don't need `case_when`, assign the conditions values directly, they already are `FALSE/TRUE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the `ifelse` function. It is a concise way of applying an either/or value:

```r
ifelse(logical_condition, value_if_yes, value_if_no)
```

There is also `if_else` which has slightly different return properties.

With this, you code becomes:

```r
df2 <- merge(merged_dataframe, dataframe, by = "dmt") %>%
         rowwise() %>%
         mutate(Morning_mean = ifelse(Morning_mean < (Morning_mean_q1 - Morning_mean_iqr)
                                    | Morning_mean > (Morning_mean_q3 + Morning_mean_iqr),
                NA,
                Morning_mean)
```

And similarly for every other row